# vmargin.sty not found

Tags: packages, titles

I have a template for a title page that I want to use. When I click compile in TexStudio, TexStudio opens the dialog to install additional packages. I click through the dialog (picture attached)

### [image: package installation dialog]

and the result is an error message "File `vmargin.sty` not found"
I found out that `vmargin.sty` is no longer used (old) and I should replace it with geometry. But I can not do that, because then I have to rewrite the whole template (and of course the template does not compile with `\usepackage{geometry}`).
Also I changed the server from where I download the package. But the result is the same.
Can you help me? Thank you.
Below I add the code of the template:

```
\documentclass{thesisclass}
% Based on thesisclass.cls of Timo Rohrberg, 2009
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Thesis - Main document
% ----------------------------------------------------------------


%% -------------------------------
%% |  Information for PDF file   |
%% -------------------------------
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Not set},
 pdftitle={Not set},
 pdfsubject={Not set},
 pdfkeywords={Not set}
}


%% ---------------------------------
%% | Information about the thesis  |
%% ---------------------------------

\newcommand{\myname}{Name}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{Title of thesis\\ 
                                        Second title line}
\newcommand{\myinstitute}{Chair for Computer Science II\\
                                                Software Engineering}

\newcommand{\reviewerone}{?}
\newcommand{\reviewertwo}{?}
\newcommand{\advisor}{?}
\newcommand{\advisortwo}{?}

\newcommand{\timestart}{XX. Monat 20XX}
\newcommand{\timeend}{XX. Monat 20XX}
\newcommand{\submissiontime}{DD. MM. 20XX}


%% ---------------------------------
%% | ToDo Marker - only for draft! |
%% ---------------------------------
% Remove this section for final version!
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{20mm}

\newcommand{\margtodo}
{\marginpar{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{ToDo}}}{}}

\newcommand{\todo}[1]
{{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{(\margtodo{}#1)}}}{}}


%% --------------------------------
%% | Old Marker - only for draft! |
%% --------------------------------
% Remove this section for final version!
\newenvironment{deprecated}
{\begin{color}{gray}}
{\end{color}}


%% --------------------------------
%% | Settings for word separation |
%% --------------------------------
% Help for separation:
% In german package the following hints are additionally available:
% "- = Additional separation
% "| = Suppress ligation and possible separation (e.g. Schaf"|fell)
% "~ = Hyphenation without separation (e.g. bergauf und "~ab)
% "= = Hyphenation with separation before and after
% "" = Separation without a hyphenation (e.g. und/""oder)

% Describe separation hints here:
\hyphenation{
% Pro-to-koll-in-stan-zen
% Ma-na-ge-ment  Netz-werk-ele-men-ten
% Netz-werk Netz-werk-re-ser-vie-rung
% Netz-werk-adap-ter Fein-ju-stier-ung
% Da-ten-strom-spe-zi-fi-ka-tion Pa-ket-rumpf
% Kon-troll-in-stanz
}


%% ------------------------
%% |    Including files   |
%% ------------------------
   % Only files listed here will be included!
   % Userful command for partially translating the document (for bug-fixing             e.g.)
   \includeonly{%
titlepage,
declaration,
introduction,
content,
evaluation,
conclusion,
appendix
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Here, main documents begins %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Remove the following line for German text
\selectlanguage{english}

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{titlepage}
\include{declaration}
\blankpage


%% -------------------
%% |   Directories   |
%% -------------------
\tableofcontents
\blankpage


%% -----------------
%% |   Main part   |
%% -----------------
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{introduction}
\include{content}
\include{evaluation}
\include{conclusion}


%% --------------------
%% |   Bibliography   |
%% --------------------
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}

\iflanguage{english}
{\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSA}}    % english style
{\bibliographystyle{babalpha-fl}}   % german style

% Use IEEEtran for numeric references
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSA})

\bibliography{thesis}


%% ----------------
%% |   Appendix   |
%% ----------------
\cleardoublepage

\input{appendix}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The package is available on TeXLive, but I don't recommend its usage at all.  Most times, it is better to drop such templates and start from scratch

Comment: It is available as `vmargin`in MiKTeX, but it has nothing to do with  `ieeepes`. Furthermore, this `thesisclass` seems  to depend on koma-script, so you might use `typearea`, if you can't use `geometry`.

Comment: As miktex is trying to download the wrong package it looks as if your package database is faulty or outdated. Go to the package manager (admin + user version) and synchronize (menu repositories) and then try again.

Comment: If you are realy realy really desperate for a template, have a look at Masters-Doctoral-Thesis which can be found on LaTeXtemplates.com.

Comment: The template you are using is based on another template which is as bad, which is based on another template that was done at a time, where `vmargin` still was ok to use. Which was a long long time ago.

Comment: Sorry, i done my homework. The template is not based on the template i was thinking about. It is based on a different template, which -- sorry to say -- isn't better either. If you want, you can have a look at [the KOMA homepage](http://www.komascript.de/node/1603) to learn a bit more about what you are working with.

Comment: Ulrike! I tried your approach and it worked. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Seems you have been of help. Do you want to add an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B I use the template you are referring to but I have the same error (vmargin.sty not found). Before I didn't have such error on Windows. Now I am on Linux Mint where I have the error.

Comment: @Sasha Get the updated version of the template. Or ... Why are you pinging me?

Comment: @Johannes_B I am sorry, didn't mean to pinging you. Was hoping to get answer and solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Sasha Just ask a new question. I have no clue what template you are talking about ;-) Rule of thumb: Don't use templates.

Answer (score 2):

As miktex is trying to download the wrong package it looks as if your local package database is faulty or outdated. You can update this database by synchronizing with the online database:

Go to the package manager (admin *and* user version) and synchronize (menu repositories) and then try again.